# Send json-body with array in it

Tags: r

I need to send post-request with json-body

The body contains a parameter cart, which is actually an array

```
"cart": [{"nid": "123","groupId": "123","price": "200.00","priceWithDiscount": "200.00","amount": "1.0"}]
```

To assemble cart i have this code (double list is for square brackets):

```
args <- list(list(price="200.00",priceWithDiscount="200.00",amount="1.0",nid="123",groupId="123"))
x <- jsonlite::toJSON(args, pretty = TRUE,auto_unbox = T)
```

And full request:

```
answer <- content(POST("https://url.com",

                         body = list(
                           sum = '200',
                           sumDiscount = '200',
                           guid = 'test_26112021',
                           number = 'test_26112021',
                           date = paste0(Sys.time()),
                           bonusAdd = '0',
                           bonusWriteOff = '0',
                           depositAdd = '0',
                           depositWriteOff = '0',
                           cart = x
                         ),encode="json"))
```

This request responds an error "The cart field must be a array." so I guess I was mistaken in this part of the code

Comment: Try wrapping it in `I` (capital i), e.g. `cart = I(x)`

Comment: same( May be it helped a bit, because error message changed on "cart: not an array."

Comment: Does the API require the `body` in list format? Or shoudl you rather create your list of list for cart, then put this together into another list called `body` and then convert this whole list to JSON and feed that into  the POST?

Comment: this works in postman https://monosnap.com/file/4ljryuKFlBbzzQgkPlZGkNeeXoBCnM

Comment: What works in postman? Your original request or my suggestion? Did you try my suggestion with the API? i'm not saying it will work, but without a working example and access to your API, it's difficult to help.

Comment: i tried to show you which query works and with what options.
if i send body 
{
    "sum": "200",
    "sumDiscount": "200",
    "guid": "test_20011",
    "number": "test_2001",
    "date": "2021-11-27 10:10:03",
    "bonusAdd": "0",
    "bonusWriteOff": "0",
    "depositAdd": "0",
    "depositWriteOff": "0",
    "cart":[{"price":"200","priceWithDiscount":"200","amount":"1.0","nid":"123","groupId":"123"}]
} 
request successful.
@deschen to be honest, I did not fully understand your proposal

Comment: What happens if you try this code:

Comment: `args1 <- list(list(price="200.00",priceWithDiscount="200.00",amount="1.0",nid="123",groupId="123"))
args2 <- list(sum = '200',
              sumDiscount = '200',
              guid = 'test_26112021',
              number = 'test_26112021',
              date = paste0(Sys.time()),
              bonusAdd = '0',
              bonusWriteOff = '0',
              depositAdd = '0',
              depositWriteOff = '0',
              cart = args1)

body <- jsonlite::toJSON(args2, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = T)

answer <- content(POST("https://url.com", body = body, encode="json"))`

Comment: @deschen the output for body in your suggestion looks exactly how it needed, but now error is "The guid field is required." so it seems, that may be query need more options to write. If i take body as you suggest in output to postman - it works correct

Comment: but then the error is pretty clear. Somewhere you need to pass a parameter `guid`. So do that.

Comment: guid is already in args2 (in your code). it is part of json-body, but it doesn't works in answer <- content(POST("https://url.com", body = body, encode="json")). In addition, the body parameter in this form you suggest works successfully in postman. So it seems to me, that query does not work completely correctly and needs to be tweaked a little so that it processes all parameters

Comment: done, it required  content_type_json() @deschen thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@deschen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159046/send-json-body-with-array-in-it/70161214#comment124024344_70159046), the solution is:

```
args1<-list(list(price="200.00",priceWithDiscount="200.00",amount="1.0",nid="123",groupId="123"))
args2<-list(guid='test_26112021',sum='200',sumDiscount='200',number='test_26112021',date=paste0(Sys.time()),bonusAdd='0',bonusWriteOff='0',depositAdd='0',depositWriteOff='0',cart=args1)
```

```
body <- jsonlite::toJSON(args2, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = T)  
answer <- content(POST("https://url.com", content_type_json(),body = body, encode="json"))
```